# DataReader GetInt32() & GetInt16()

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to read a `smallint` column value using SqlDataReader.

The `dataReader.GetInt32()` is throwing exception as "The specified cast is not valid."

But

> dataReader.GetInt16()

is working fine too.

Can you someone explain why the GetInt32() fails provided Int16 can be assigned to Int32 as here

```
 Int16 i16 = 1;
 Int32 i32 = i16;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `GetInt##()` methods look for an exact match, the 'invalid cast' error is about the DbType to ClrType conversion.

You are correct that GetInt32() could have been made to read smaller types but then that could happen inadvertently as well.

Should `GetDouble()` read `int`, `long` and maybe even `decimal` without complaining?
I think better not.

Comment: Sometimes it is not obvious what the underlying database type is.  I got caught with this.  Even if the value can be cast as an Int32, but is defined in the database as an nvarchar - this will throw an exception

Comment: Is there a way to check before calling either method?  I'm hoping I can create a helper extension that's something like `getInt16Or32` that's the honey badger of getInt methods - just don't care. Just get me an int.

Comment: @Snekse - sure, should be easy to write. There is `GetValue()` (and then use type-casting or `GetFieldType()` ).

Comment: Perfect. `switch (Type.GetTypeCode(rs.GetFieldType(colIdx)))` with `case TypeCode.Int32: return rs.GetInt32(colIdx)`